# Undefined control sequence from template

Tags: errors

I have problem with my template. Whenever I want to include one of object from my template it gives me a problem;

```
Undefined control sequence
```

My `file.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{dipp}
\usepackage[utf8, latin2]{inputenc} % Kódování
\usepackage[english, czech]{babel} % Čeština
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % České fonty
\begin{document}
\inputencoding{utf8}
\skola{text}
\fakulta{text}
\titul{text}{text}{text}{text}
\podekovani{text}
\prohlaseni{text...}
\abstract{abstracteng}{text} %% the error ocurs after adding this line
%\abstrakt{asdd}{asdd}
\obsah %%content
%%ok text stuff
\end{document}
```

My `style.tex`:

```
\def\abstract#1#2{\cleardoublepage\vspace*{3cm}{\english
   \noindent {\sffamily\bfseries Abstract}\par\medskip
   \noindent #1 \par \medskip #2}}

\def\abstrakt#1#2{\vspace*{3cm}{\noindent
  {\sffamily\bfseries Abstrakt}\par\medskip
   \noindent #1 \par \medskip #2}}
```

My error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\abstract ...ardoublepage \vspace *{3cm}{\english 
                                              \noindent {\sffamily \bfse...
l.33 \abstract{abstracteng}{text}

?
```

Do you know what could be wrong with this? It makes me very bloody minded.

Comment: Seems that `\english` is undefined. What should it do?

Comment: Should be style of one page with anotation. My definition of languages is like I've immediately added.

Comment: Well, if you want to switch the language you have to use instead `\setlanguage{english}`. But I would use this *outside* before your `abstract` environment ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Yes, the problem was with two languages. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we found out with several comments, the problem is that the macro `\english` is not definded. That causes the given error.

To solve your problem use `\setlanguage{english}` instead. That switches the language for the document to english, including the special LaTeX names like `\refname` etc.